# When I use markdown my first element is not formatted like the other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I'm following a tutorial about how to use markdown and when I do this

```
# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
##### H5
###### H6
```

H1 is wrapped in a well. When I look at the out put from the console it shows

```
<p class="content-markdown"><pre><code>   # H1
  </code></pre><h2 id="h2">H2</h2>
  <h3 id="h3">H3</h3>
  <h4 id="h4">H4</h4>
  <h5 id="h5">H5</h5>
  <h6 id="h6">H6</h6>
  <h2 id="alt-h2">Alt-H2</h2>
</p>
```

if I ad an

```
#
```

above h1, it displays fine but then the bang sign is now in a well

here is my script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content-markdown").each(function(){
    var content =  $(this).text()
    console.log(content)
    var markedContent = marked(content)
    console.log(markedContent)
    $(this).html(markedContent)
    })
})
```

and this is in my head tag, not that I think that matters but I could be wrong

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
```

what could be causing this? All guidance is welcome

Comment: This is an specific issue with the markdown parser you're using in your web site... PageDown, the one used by StackExchange (and developed by them too) doesn't get this problem..

Comment: what's causing it? becaus in the tutorial video I'm watching this isn't happening

Comment: It appears that you have some extra whitespace at the beginning of your Markdown document. As you are pulling the Markdown from within your HTML document (but you don't show that part), check your HTML for whitespace.

Comment: @Waylan thats exactly what it was. Removed the whitespace and it worked fine. I'f you answered I could have given you credit

Comment: I've just copied my comment to an answer. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have some extra whitespace at the beginning of your Markdown document. As you are pulling the Markdown from within your HTML document (but you don't show that part), check your HTML for whitespace.